# Как сделать правильно действие во временной промежуток?

Tags: php

**Задача:** Менять ответственного у заявки, если в течении определенного времени  не было произведено хотя бы какого-то действия с заявкой.

**Пример:**
время поступления заявки: 14:47
время ожидания до смены сотрудника: 10 минут
Скрипт срабатывает например каждые 5 минут, т.е. будет срабатывать в 14:00, 14:05 ... 14:50, 14:55

```
$resultContacts = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE status_view != '1' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");

            if ($resultContacts->num_rows) {

                while($rowContacts = $resultContacts->fetch_assoc()){

                    $id_staff_old = $rowContacts['id_staff']; // ID старого сотрудника
                    // Устанавливаем текущее время согласно часовому поясу
                    $now_date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time() + $rowTimezone['timezone_plus']));
                    // Составляем время дедлайна
                    $date_choice_staff = strtotime($rowContacts['date_choice_staff']);
                    // Расчитываем время переключения на другого сотрудника
                    $change_date = $date_choice_staff+($rowCabinet['auto_switch_wait']*60);
                    // Устанавливаем промежуток времени для срабатывания переключения сотрудника
                    $limit_change_date = (5*60)+$change_date;

                    // Выполняем если текущее время больше или равно дате переключения сотрудника И текущее время меньше или равно промежутку в которое должно сработать смена сотрудника.
                    if ($now_date >= $change_date and $limit_change_date >= $now_date) {
                        echo "<b>".$rowContacts['id']."____________<br>";
                        echo "".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$now_date)."<br>";
                        echo "".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$change_date)."<br>";
                        echo "".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$limit_change_date)."<br></b>";

                    } else {
                        echo "".$rowContacts['id']."____________<br>";
                        echo "".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$now_date)."<br>";
                        echo "".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$change_date)."<br>";
                        echo "".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$limit_change_date)."<br>";
                    }

                }

            }
```

Скрипт, ищет в базе все  не просмотренные заявки. В базе есть **время назначения ответственного** `date_choice_staff`, это время будет меняться при назначении нового ответственного его мы берем за основу и прибавляем **установленное время ожидания переключения** `auto_switch_wait`, получается **время когда нужно сменить ответственного** `$change_date`. Так же устанавливаем промежуток времени в рамках которого скрипт берет все заявки и меняет в них ответственного `$limit_change_date` = `$change_date` + 5 минут

Далее идет условие: Выполняем, если текущее время больше или равно дате переключения ответственного И текущее время меньше или равно промежутку в которое должно сработать смена ответственного.

**Проблема:** Получается, если заявка пришла в 14:47 к этому времени добавляем время ожидания 10 минут, получается сменить ответственного надо в 14:57, скрипт срабатывает в 14:55 (шаг 5 минут), скрипт возьмет все заявки у которых время смены будет умещаться в промежуток между 14:55 и 15:00, то получается заявка у которой смена сотрудника должна быть в 14:57 произойдет в 14:55, т.е. на 2 минуты раньше... **что не хорошо**

**1) Не уверен в правильности условия, подскажите, если что не так!**

**2) Мне получается нужно сделать CRON задание каждую минуту? Получается много запросов будет к базе за сутки =/**

Comment: вопрос в том, с какой точностью, вы хотите отслеживать событие. Дальше допустимую  ошибку умножаете на два, получаете частоту запуска. Сменять, когда время не прошло, наверное, менее правильно

Comment: *Мне получается нужно сделать CRON задание каждую минуту? Получается много запросов будет к базе за сутки* Один запрос в минуту - фигня. К тому же при правильно построенных условиях отбора результат будет ма-а-аленький...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Округляйте время смены сотрудника до ближайшего значения шага. При этом время ожидания заявки считайте в диапазоне `8-12 минут`.

Поступила заявка в `14:47`. Время смены ответственного у заявки `14:57 - 2 минуты`. Смена произойдёт через 8 минут.

Поступила заявка в `14:48`. Время смены ответственного у заявки `14:58 + 2 минуты`. Смена произойдёт через 12 минут.

Comment: ну или делать реально каждую минуту крон

Comment: *При этом время ожидания заявки считайте в диапазоне 8-12 минут* Лучше, наверное, >=8 минут... ну чтобы наверняка ничего не пропустить.

Comment: А при шаге проверки в 5 минут и округлении смены, она может быть только в диапазоне 8-12 минут.